# Memory issues while processing large C arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, audio, memory, segmentation-fault

**EDIT:** Turns out I didn't need to multiply by FRAMESIZE. frames comes from the libsndfile API (which I had overlooked) and the semantics are different than how frames are defined in my program. So in is size frames * 2 and mono is size frames.

I've accepted an answer below that isn't entirely correct but pushed me in the right direction. Thanks jxh.

---

I'm doing some audio work, writing an effect in C++. I have an input source that is an interleaved 2-channel array of samples. I have found that the function that turns that stereo array into a mono array (`getMono()`) is causing some *massive* memory bloat (12.7MB before, 3.69GB after) after just one call. It is also extremely slow. The stereo array, in my test case, is of size 800254.

I'm relatively new to C++. I did a lot of embedded C in college, but nothing like this. So, this could be a beginner error.

I've trimmed down my code to the very smallest amount of code needed to both understand and reproduce the error. Essentially, setInput gets called in the Sukothai constructor and then generates a mono version of the input array.

```
#define SAMPLE float    
#define RANDOMWIN .5
#define FRAMESIZE 512


void Sukothai::getMono(SAMPLE * stereo, SAMPLE * mono, int monoSize){
  for (int j = 0; j < monoSize; j++) {
    mono[j] = .7071*(stereo[j*2] + stereo[j*2+1]);
  }
}

void Sukothai::setInput(SAMPLE * in, int frames) {
  // per-iteration additional time in terms of seconds
  //float extraTime = RANDOMWIN*2;

  // new buffer size in terms of samples
  //int newSize = ((int)(maxIter*extraTime*2*THE_SRATE)+frames*FRAMESIZE*2);

  //SAMPLE * current_buffer = new SAMPLE[newSize];

  SAMPLE * mono;
  int currentMonoSize = 0;

  currentMonoSize = frames*FRAMESIZE;
  mono = new SAMPLE[currentMonoSize];
  getMono(in, mono, currentMonoSize);
}
```

Now, there are three lines here that are commented out. Those lines create the variables `extraTime`, `newSize`, and `current_buffer`. These are all part of a different part of my effect. I've commented them out here to show that they don't have to do with the stereo to mono functionality, but if I comment them out in my code, I have a segmentation fault.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

**EDIT:** added FRAMESIZE define

Comment: What is `FRAMESIZE`?

Comment: Ah. FRAMESIZE is 512. Sorry. I'll add that in the description. This larger program divides an audio signal into frames that are of size 512. So there are 512 left samples and 512 right samples in each frame.

Comment: What does `frames` represent? The number of element in `in`?

Comment: Yes. Passing in the size of the array so I can use that knowledge later.

Comment: Your code leaks `mono`, since the array is never returned, nor freed before the function returns.

Comment: So an hour or so ago, I added `delete [] mono` and still had memory problems.

Comment: Reading beyond your array boundaries will cause memory problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have `frames` elements in the input array `in`, and you compute `currentMonoSize` to be `512` times that amount. Then, in `getMono()`, you proceed to read from `in` (not called `stereo`) twice the number of `currentMonoSize`. This means you are reading well beyond what you had specified to be the number of elements in `in`.

Logically, the `mono` array should have half as many elements as the `stereo` input.

Comment: The array `in` is of size `FRAMESIZE * frames * 2`. That's the number of frames, times the frame size, times 2 (for stereo). That is double `currentMonoSize`.

Comment: If `frames` is the size of `in`, you compute `mono` to be larger than that, always.

Comment: It's not. `FRAMESIZE * frames * 2` is the size of `in`.

Comment: I asked: "What does `frames` represent? The number of elements in `in`?", and you answered: "Yes."

Comment: Yeah, I know. I clarified it above. But hey, you pushed me in the right direction, whether or not it was exactly right. I appreciate it.

Turns out I didn't need to multiply by `FRAMESIZE`. `frames` comes from the libsndfile API (which I had overlooked) and the semantics are different than how frames are defined in my program. So `in` is size `frames * 2` and mono is size `frames`. 

Thanks again.